# Returning boolean instead of declaring a void type in Java?

Tags: java, boolean, void

Are there any hard and fast rules regarding returning boolean in a method signature to indicate a successful operation as opposed to declaring void? I find that for more critical operations in my calling method I want to know if an operation completed so I can log any issues. Is this an "inappropriate" use of boolean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Usually I use `Exception`s to signal when something went wrong.

Instead of returning `false`, you can `throw` an `Exception` with a detailed message about what the problem was.

Returning `false` doesn't give you much information about the problem.

Then, instead of checking for a `false` return value, just put the method call in `try`/`catch` if you expect that the method could easily fail.

Many people will complain that this method is slower.  But, the benefits you gain greatly outweigh the slowdown.  Besides, if you are using Java speed shouldn't be your #1 concern.

Comment: And exceptions should be, well, exceptional.  So the speed difference should be material.

Answer (score 6):

I generally find that throwing an exception in the case of a failure is a far better solution than returning a boolean, because generally do not care if the process has succeeded - I only care if it's failed. By using an exception I can provide any amount of information about why the process actually failed.

If exceptions seem distasteful, you can return a custom Status object which contains a boolean and a status message (something like "Added 6 new Foobars!" or "Could not add Foobars because the Foobin is full!"), although that is of course more complex.

Answer (score 4):

Only do this in scenarios where it's clear that something has a boolean outcome. Like `IsValidCustomer()` or some such.

For all other things where you *think* you could introduce it, it probably means you're dealing with some kind of `Exception`, and you really don't want to wrap that with a simple boolean `true/false`, because you can have a variety of flavours (different exceptions) and reasons why something goes wrong, which you would want to know about.

So either let the exception bubble up the stack, or catch it and turn it into a custom exception or log it or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Use boolean values to indicate non-exceptional failure outcomes.  An example would be a search function. The nominal failure would be *not-found*. Communicating that outcome with exceptions is unwieldy. Save exceptions for exceptional cases; the difference between *not-found* and *cannot-search*.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ok paradigm, but if you want to force the caller to handle the case wehre the operation doesn't complete successfully, you might want to throw a checked exception instead.

This pattern does occur in the core Java libraries, though.  See [File.delete()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) as an example.

Comment: -1: This is not an "OK" paradigm; it's a horrible recipe for disaster caused by "blundering on" after an error.

Comment: I think you've got a lot of down-voting ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

For returning success generally what you see is:

- Return a boolean
- Return void, but throw exception on error
- Return a status code (less common in java).

Can't see anything wrong with returning a boolean for success, unless you'd need information on exception behavior.

Comment: The (potential) problem with returning boolean for success is the ease with which one can ignore the boolean for failure. Even a runtime exception is much louder and less likely to be overlooked during both coding and testing.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an unexpected result, throw an exception.
If you just want the function to tell you "did I do X" then return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, I find that throwing an Exception is the best thing to do when failure means that we need to abort the process. Like, if you're trying to process an order -- bill the customer, arrange shipping, pay sales taxes, etc -- if you can't find the order record, there's probably little point in doing all the other work. You just want to get out of there. Exceptions let you do this easily. Just catch at the bottom of the block, display or log the error, and get out.

On the other hand, if an "error" means that my program takes a different flow path, returning a boolean makes more sense. Like, if I'm looking for a specific customer and if he exists I update his record and if he doesn't I create a new customer record, then it makes a lot of sense to return a boolean, and in the caller test it and when true follow one path and when false the other.

Really this is two very different meanings of the word "error", and they call for different handling. It is quite possible that the same function could do both. Like, on found return true, on not found return false, on I/O error trying to read throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seem ok, but the devil lies into the details. ;-)

Throwing an exception is the main alternative, with pros and cons.

I think you could get more insight by providing precise coding samples...